# Geodesics of the right circular cone

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I have to find teh geodesics of the cone:

$$C={(x,y,z)\in R^3:x^2+y^2=z^2,z>0}$$

My idea is use that the geodesic curvature must be 0 for be a geodesic.Then I use the parametrization:

$$X(u,v)=(ucosv,usinv,u)$$

but I get this conclusion:

$Xu=(cosv,sinv,1)$ $Xv=(-usinv,ucosv,0)$$Xu\times Xv=(-ucosv,-usinv,1)$

$norm(Xu\times Xv)=u\sqrt{2}$

$N=\frac{Xu\times Xv}{norm(Xu\times Xv)}=(-cosv/\sqrt{2},-sinv/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$

$alpha'(v)=(-usinv,ucosv,0)$$alpha''(v)=(-ucosv,-usonv,0)$

$Kg=det\left(\begin{array}{c}alpha''(v)\\N\\alpha'(v)\end{array}\right)$

$$Kg=\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}} \Rightarrow Kg=0 \Leftrightarrow u=0$$

And it doesn't have any sense to me. So, which is the way to get the geodesics and why my idea doesn't work?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you include the details of your work? We can't begin to guess how you've come up with what you posted. By the way, do you know how to see the geodesics by "unrolling" the cone into a piece of paper?

Comment: No, I don't know how to see the geodesics with that. Sorry I don't know too much about it, I only know that $Kg=0$ and try to use it. If you want to know how I get this $Kg$ I will try to improve my question.

Comment: So you've learned that the $v$-curves on the cone are *not* geodesics. You need to take a general curve, not the curve $\alpha(v) = X(u,v)$ (for $u$ fixed). You should be able to see geometrically that these circles are *not* geodesics — after all, the acceleration vector is *not* normal to the surface.

Answer (score 3):

This won't help you with your computations, 
but I would just like to observe that
when the cone is cut open and unrolled flat, 
the geodesics are straight line segments.

---

[image: Cone]

          

<sup>Image from [Mark Irons](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/Creations/Puzzles/cone.geodesics/index.html).</sup>

---